# oxm.marshaller: create xml temporarily and use it for xslt pdf generation (java)

Tags: java, xml, file, xslt

I'm struggeling with storing a streamresult .xml file temporarily and use it to create a pdf with xslt.

I have a method (methodCalled) that creates an empty file. It passes that empty file and an object with data to a methode objectToXml in the xmlConverter Class. When I execute, I always get a nullpointer exception on the line with os.close() in the xmlConverter Class. Can you help me to understand why this happens?

It works fine when I pass a String (with a filepath) instead of the file object to `new FileOutputStream(file);`.

```
public function methodCalled() {
        File file = new File(".");      
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            xmlConverter.objectToXml(file, expense);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Class xmlConverter:

```
public class XmlConverter {

    @Autowired
    private Marshaller marshaller;

    public void objectToXml(File file, Object object) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            marshaller.marshal(object, new StreamResult(os));

        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help guys :)